# Using WMI to monitor event log

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to use WMI to monitor the event log for EntryWritten events, so I set up the handler as follows:

```
// Create the event log monitor
        string query = "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Where TargetInstance.LogFile='Application'";
        WqlEventQuery aProcessCreationQuery = new WqlEventQuery(query);
        ManagementEventWatcher aWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(aProcessCreationQuery);
        aWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(EventLogMonitor);
```

But my handler method EventLogMonitor never fires, even when things are being written to the Application Event log. My application runs as a service monitoring for things written to the event log.

I found somewhere that I may need to add the line:

```
aWatcher.Start()
```

in the StartService() method, but if I do the service wont start. I wonder if anybody has any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You WQL senence is wrong 
`Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Where TargetInstance.LogFile='Application'`

you must include the class which you are inspecting in the sentence using the `ISA` keyword

Something like so

`Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' and TargetInstance.LogFile='Application'`